# How do you "Edit As New" in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Thunderbird, there's the option to "Edit As New...".

[image]

When selecting that option, I can edit the original message and send it like a new message.

How can I do the same thing in Outlook?

*Note: This question is about the **native Outlook Client** (up to Outlook 2019). For the web client, aka "Outlook Web Access", "Outlook on the web", or "Outlook 365", see [How do you "Edit As New" in Outlook Online?](https://superuser.com/questions/1370266/how-do-you-edit-as-new-in-outlook-online) .*

Comment: How do you do it in OWA?

Comment: @Peltier: See [How do you "Edit As New" in Outlook Online?](https://superuser.com/questions/1370266/how-do-you-edit-as-new-in-outlook-online)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In Outlook, the functionality is named **Resend This Message**. 
See instructions for different versions of Outlook below.

### Outlook 2010

When opening a *sent* message, you'll find the option in the **Move** panel under **Actions**:

[image]

In a *received* message, you'll find the option in the **Respond** panel:

[image]

Either of these will open the message in a new window where you can edit the message like a new email.

### Outlook 2013, 2016, and 2019

In Outlook 2013, 2016, and 2019, the action is available in the **Move** panel under **Actions** for both types of messages.

Note that the **Actions** menu is not available in the main Outlook window, but you must open the message by double-clicking it, and then select the action from the message's own, slightly different, ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or does those screenshots not actually show what the text suggests?

Comment: @AdamThompson: It must be you. It looks fine to me. Anything in particular that doesn't match up from your point of view?

Comment: Is there anyway to resend without opening the message? In Thunderbird I could simply right click in the mail list and edit as new. I tried adding the resend button to quick access toolbar but it's still not available outside the message window

Comment: Most shortcuts are indeed a lot easier in Thunderbird... I just press control-E to "edit as new" there. In Outlook, make sure you first open the email in a new window (double click it), only then will these options appear.

Comment: In O365 I do not find this resend, there is no "action" as written in the answer.

Comment: Hi @Timo. 
Oh, dear. I would think, then, that if you specified it was for Office 365 and not for a permanent version, maybe even including a link to this question, you should be justified in asking a new question.

Comment: @Post169 thanks, I will try [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resend-an-email-message-acd16ac4-c881-477d-b4aa-36168fa96088) on monday and let you know here my user experience.

Comment: Microsoft don't make it easy for you, do they.

Answer (score 2):

For Outlook 2011 for Mac:

1. Navigate to your "Sent Items" folder
2. Highlight the message you want to "Edit as New"
3. Click on the "Message" menu item, and select "Resend"

Answer (score 0):

A similar story applies to Outlook 2007:

Open the sent message.  Click "Other Actions" in the message's ribbon.  Click "Resend this message...".