# How do you "Edit As New" in Outlook Online?

Tags: email, office365, web-application

I want to edit and send again a message that I sent with Outlook Online (in outlook.office.com, part of Office 365). [This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/579641/how-do-you-edit-as-new-in-outlook) explains how to do it in Microsoft Outlook but the options in Outlook Online are different and I don't see "Resend this message". Is it possible?

If I right-click on an email that I already sent, it opens this contextual menu:

[image]

After I double-click on such an email, I see a new window with the contents of the email and these three sections with buttons at the top, under the three dots, and at the right:

[image: Buttons at the top]
[image: Expansion of the three dots]
[image: Buttons at the right]

Comment: Are you sure you're using an Office 365 subscription and not the free Outlook.com email?

Comment: Yes, I have the full suite at work (calendar, outlook, word, sharepoint, onedrive, etc.). Do you see that option in your Office 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to "Forward" the message and delete the extra header and information that Outlook adds both to the subject and the body.

Answer (score 2):

**As of 2018, this answer no longer applies - apparently the functionality was removed.**

---

The procedure is exactly the same as for the desktop Office version.

To resend emails as if they were new messages :

1. Open Outlook.
2. Click the *Sent Items* mailbox located in the left-hand pane.
3. Double-click an email you would like to resend.
4. In the new window, the Move group, click the **Actions** button and then click
   *Resend This Message...*
5. A copy of the message will appear that you may edit and send.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the buttons for step 4. I added two screenshots of what I do have in the question.

Comment: The interface has changed. Don't you have a Move group, or is it hiding behind the three dots?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a screenshot of the three dots after checking that the Move group was missing. I added that in the question.

Comment: Do you have something useful in the right-click menu for the email item?

Comment: I do have a "Move" group in the contextual menu, but not "Resend this message". I edited the question with a screenshot. If I click on "Move to a different folder", a box appears with a list of folders, but not "Resend this message".

Comment: It's no longer there! As a workaround, can you use Forward instead?

Comment: Too bad! Forward does work, except for keeping the recipients, which I need to copy-paste them one by one. Shall we wait a few days to see if the UI changes back again?

Comment: Don't hold your breath... You might report this missing option to Microsoft, or search for an existing request and add your voice.

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2023, there is no "Resend" option in Microsoft Outlook for the web.

There are several people in the Outlook Feedback forum asking for this (e.g. [Resend feature in Outlook Web app](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/b1e7ebc8-8248-ed11-a81b-6045bd7fe4d3)), but no response so far.